# Pardot - Connected Campaigns

Tags: pardot

My organization is considering using Connected Campaigns in Pardot, the feature to link Pardot Campaigns and Salesforce Campaigns. We are curious if this will allow us to use Salesforce Campaign fields (for example, campaign start date or location) as variable tags in an email. I can't find this information online.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about utilizing salesforce CRM's email functionality then yes but if you are trying to use these variables in Pardot email then you can not perform this action. only few variables apart from the custom and default fields are available even after you enable connected campaigns,